# Benefits of using an off-hand parrying object in 7th Sea

Tags: 7th-sea

To put it simple: Why would you (besides a matter of fighting style) choose to parry using your off-hand (either with buckler, main gauche, cloak, etc.) instead of your weapon?

As far as I understand, you get a -1 unkept die penalty for using the off-hand AND you must buy another skill for using the parrying object, instead of simply buying the parry knack under your weapon skill. I feel there must be something I'm missing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mechanically, there is effectively no reason to use your off-hand to parry, unless you have a swordsman school.**

You're not missing anything. That's just the way the mechanics work. There are a very few items that reward you for parrying with them (such as the Shield in the Vesten source book), but these are few and their effects are minor.

An off-hand parry weapon also gives you a fallback if your main weapon is sundered or disarmed. But Footwork/Balance provide a better fallback, and being without a weapon for long doesn't happen often.

From a RAW standpoint, you usually want to work up three key defensive skills:

- Your parry, with your primary weapon (because it works as long as you are armed).
- Footwork (situational, but works against firearms).
- Balance (situational, but works against firearms).

There are certainly flavor reasons why you might want to parry with an off-hand weapon. Panzerhands beg to be used, and a sword/main gauche combo has a nice look to it. But *mechanically*, there's no reason not to just parry with your main hand.

**As a house rule, you might consider negating the off-hand penalty for parrying.**

Because of the way actions work in *7th Sea*, this shouldn't break too much. The swordsman schools still get their +5 to make them special. And focusing on your main-hand weapon is still the optimal build... Just not *so* optimal that choosing to use an off-hand weapon for parrying feels like a penalty.

Just be sure to keep the penalty in place for attacks, and other non-parry actions. Otherwise you might end up with everyone carrying a pistol in their off-hand instead of a buckler.

Comment: My objection to the house rule is that when you buy a school, you are paying points to negate that penalty.  It's kind of like saying you get +1k0+5 to your AD being reduced to just +5.  While a minimal (2-3pt advantage worth) change, it seems a bit of a robbery from an already steep cost.

Comment: @CatLord It's in how you see it, I guess. I don't really see it as a +1k0 + 5 bonus, because I'd never use an off-hand object to parry with the penalty. I'd be looking at the options "take school, and get parry + 5" or "don't take school, get parry +0 (with main hand)." Also, if a player is really in love with the idea of Panzerhands, but doesn't like Eisenfaust, I'm not sure I want to penalize that kind of stylization/fluff.

Comment: Point taken, although it's not a house rule I myself would use.  Also I would like your take on sort of a middle ground we both initially overlooked and added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, it doesn't matter what the off hand object is.  If you want to have two swords and parry with one and not the other you can use the same skill, but if you want different things then yes you need the other skill as you've said.

The bottom line is that there is no "Ambidexterity" advantage that other games might boast.  The Left Handed advantage only affects your attacks and not your parries so it wouldn't negate the penalty overall. So the very common Apprentice level ability NOHP (No Off Hand Penalty) bonus is the only way I've seen to do it.  Thus you require a Swordsman School if you wish to have a dual weapon fighting style.

That being said, the only reason I could see a character insisting on using their off hand for anything is RP purposes.  They may have a Hubris such as Overconfident, or you may have someone like the famed Inigo Montoya ("[To duel him left handed]  is only way I can be satisfied. If I use my right... over too quickly").  Even further, they could be a fledgling in a school but not have graduated to the Apprentice level such as buying a Swordsman School with XP.  Thus, a character vying to be in the Valroux school might start doing a rapier/main gauche thing because in character they want to get used to doing so.  As a GM, I don't let character just randomly buy knacks without having a good reason, so in this circumstance, yes I'd make them at least do a small sparring scene with another character showing they are working on it behind the main story.

If a character wants to *hold* an off hand parrying item, they can still use their Footwork as their Passive defense so they *look* like they are using a style they know exists to fool a prospective opponent.

Edit: It comes to pass that I've seen **no penalty to Passive Defense** when using an item in your off hand.  The rule only says -1k0 to rolls, but does not list any exceptions for passive defense or other rules determined by your skill level in the item in question.  So if you have a Parry(Knife) 3, your PD is 20 but you only get 2k0 towards your AD if it's in your offhand.  So if you're running a character who doesn't use Active Defense much (especially low Wits characters) the penalty is effectively ignored unless you choose to attack with the offhand weapon.

Comment: Added an edit to my answer that occurred to me while I was out and about.

Comment: Good observation on the passive defense. You're still paying extra (buying an extra skill) for a penalty (everyone should AD *sometimes*), but the potential rarity of the penalty helps mitigate it a lot.